# How to parse json array without json tag

Tags: android, arrays, getjson

How do I parse this JSON. As you see it does not contains any tag.

```
[
"~/Uploads/modern-appartment-quiet-place-e0cf951cf47cd1b5867a6d896f692a0b.jpg",
"~/Uploads/rockthathorse_appartment_01.jpg",
"~/Uploads/Untitled.png"
 ]
```

If any developer know how to parse these type of json array in android please help me.

Comment: Put in your code and put in some context. We are not mind readers here.

Comment: "How to parse"? You could use JSONArray...?

Comment: What problem getting in parsing posted simple JSONArray?

Answer (score 5):

Store your `JSON` as a `String`

```
String asd = "[\"~/Uploads/modern-appartment-quiet-place-e0cf951cf47cd1b5867a6d896f692a0b.jpg\",\"~/Uploads/rockthathorse_appartment_01.jpg\",\"~/Uploads/Untitled.png\"]";

JSONArray jre;
try 
{
    jre = new JSONArray(asd);

   for (int i = 0; i < jre.length(); i++) 
    {
        String a = jre.getString(i);
        Log.d("J", a);
    }


} catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over json array and access using index

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  String value =  arrayJson.get(i);
}
```

Is that what you want? Otherwise update your question with complete json details.

Comment: Thank deniz, it really very nice solutions